# Is there a good reason to avoid FOR loops without a final-expression in JS?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, jslint

Is it a bad habit to write reverse loops as:

```
for (i = N; i--;)
```

in order to access (N-1) to 0

If so, why? jsLint certainly doesn't like it.

Comment: Your code won't work. It should be `for (i = N; i > 0; i--);`. I don't know why you would do this, though. `N` will still be its original value. `i` will be 0 by the end. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Readability is the only reason that immediately springs to mind.

Comment: Another more common syntax for reverse loops is `while(i--)`

Comment: @benekastah: It certainly does work.  Remember that the second expression in a [`for`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.6.3) statement determines whether or not the loop continues; when `i` reaches `0`, the second expression will be falsy, so the loop stops.  (Also, benekastah's comment inadvertently validates my comment that this isn't readable.)

Comment: @benekastah oh it certainly works http://jsfiddle.net/sU3HL/ it just does the decrement during the "condition" instead of using a final-expression.

Comment: @Sinetheta Are you iterating over an array or array-like object? In that case you may want to use `forEach()` or one of the other iteration methods instead.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: You can't iterate in reverse using `forEach`.

Comment: +1 to the above.`for` loop in javascript is a bad habit in general.

Comment: @am not i am: `ary.reverse().forEach()`

Comment: I see what's going on now. I assumed you would be omitting the body of the for loop (hence the semicolon at the end of my attempted correction earlier).

Comment: @thg435: *"for loop in javascript is a bad habit in general"* You've got to be joking, right? And `.reverse()` modifies the Array, which likely isn't wanted. You're still iterating in ascending order.

Comment: ...and you can't `break` a `forEach`. And `forEach` skips `undefined` members, which may not be wanted.

Comment: @amnotiam: `forEach` is named so for a reason. It calls a callback for each element, literally. If you intend to `break`, you want `some()`, not `forEach()`.

Comment: @amnotiam, @thg435: What you really want is [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which stops if a callback returns `false`.

Comment: None of these alternatives iterate in reverse. To call a `for` loop "bad practice" is just silly. But yes, those will allow you to halt the loop.

Comment: @josh3736: I guess it's a matter of preference whether to return true or false from an iterator in order to stop. Throw `StopIteration` is another common pattern.

Comment: @thg435: Again, a readability thing.  It makes more sense to return `false` to stop iteration.  Consider jQuery event handlers -- you return `false` if you want to prevent default/stop propagation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no technical reason that this won't work.  However, it [clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135549/is-there-a-good-reason-to-avoid-for-loops-without-a-final-expression-in-js/9135860#comment11482711_9135549) has readability issues since someone had an immediate "well that won't work!" reaction.

This is the kind of issue that the jQuery team [struggles with](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10753#comment:2) – whether to use novel constructs that save bytes at the expense of clarity and maintainability.  It really comes down to whether it's worth 1 or 3 bytes of savings:

```
for(var i=9;i--;)
var i=9;while(i--)
for(var i=9;i>0;i--)
```

In this case, probably not.

Comment: This seems to be the consensus. Thanks to all the answers, but josh has really summed it up here.

Answer (score 4):

It is less readable, without your explanation it would take me few seconds to understand what the loop does. Why not simply:

```
while(i-- > 0)
```

?

Comment: Good question. Although I think the equivalent would be `while(i--)`. So the same applies, is this "readable"?

Answer (score 4):

Did you consider readability? You may very well understand it yourself, but other developers might get confused since the parts of the `for` "idiom" are [usually named as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

While the condition can technically be any expression, your version does not conform to this idiom, since the "condition" part you use does more than just defining a condition - it sneakily decrements `i` as well.

Comment: This is what I figured. It seems to be a fairly common pattern these days, but if it's enough to get "that won't work" on SO then I guess it's not as readable as I though.

Comment: @Sinetheta: It is not necessarily unreadable, but I'd say putting the decrementing and condition parts in the appropriate, separate, parts of the `for` loop doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is it a bad habit to write reverse loops as:"*
>
> ```
> for (i = N; i--;)
> ```

That's a matter of opinion, but it's effectively a reverse `while` with initialization, so in my *opinion* it's not a *"bad habit"*. It's just a coding style.

The *specification* makes the parts of a `for` *optional* to give the developer that flexibility.

> *"jsLint certainly doesn't like it."*

Who cares. You're not bound to follow the opinions of jsLint.

Answer (score 1):

The answers would be very subjective I guess. I don't think it is a bad habit but I do find it aesthetically unpleasing. This can be expressed more elegantly as:

```
for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // do something here.
}

// And if it is really important that i should be 0 here
// as it is in your original code.
i = 0
```

This code is easier on our brain while browsing a lot of code that happens to contain this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a good reason. Readability.